# Designing how much to abstract a setter/modifier

Tags: java, design-patterns, setter

My application receives XML messages to update it's data objects. The XML message contains details on how the data is to be modified. The XML looks something like:

```
<data>
   <stuff> .... </stuff>
   <stuff> .... </stuff>
   <objs>
      <obj attr1=... attr2=... />
      <obj attr1=... attr2=... />
   </objs>
</data>
```

How should I update the fields of the objects?

1. Create a modify(String xml) method. Parse the message, extract `<stuff>` data, then reconstruct the following `<obj attr1=... />` as a String and pass into modify().
2. Create a modify(NamedNodeMap xml) method. Parse the message, extract `<stuff>` data, keep the results of the parsing (Document object), find the relevant Node and pass into modify().
3. Create a modify(String attr1, String attr2, ...) method. Parse the XML, extract the fields, pass into modify(). Probably a very bad idea, because if I need more attributes, I need the change the method signature, and breaks everything that depend on the modify() method.
4. Create setters for every field. Parse the XML, then set the fields individually. Then we run into the whole getter and setter debate, and in the context of this application, the fields of my data objects should only be modified by these XML messages, not anywhere else.

Personally I'm torn between 1 and 2. I think 1 would be more flexible, in case we decided not to use DOM, I can change how the String is parsed inside the modify(String xml) method. But then I would have to parse the XML twice, once to obtain the `<stuff>` data, then reconstructing the XML as String, and being parsed again inside the modify() method.

Should XML parsing even be done inside my data classes? Is there any reason to choose the other choices? Thanks.

[Edit]
In general, how much should I "unpack" data before passing into a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest option 4, mostly because you probably don't want your data objects to be so closely tied to the message transport mechanism.

With options 1 and 2 if you decide to change your XML schema (or if you decide that XML is too verbose, or if you want to include encryption etc etc) then you probably now have to change your data object implementation - the same reason that option 3 is bad.

Are you absolutely certain that your current set of XML messages will be the only reason that data will change, ever? I mean *really* absolutely 100% certain that no-one will ever not want to use XML? If not, then go with 4. Decoupling implementation (data object) from interface (XML messages) is the best way to ensure your code is maintainable.

Comment: I'm currently not favouring the setter solution because previously the project ABUSED setters. I'm trying to disable setters which aren't required and control how other objects modify the internal state of my data objects. Of course some setters do make their way into the data classes, but the other fields are initialised on construction, or modified by XML. I understand your POV, but I'm still trying to see how I can move away from massive setters in my class.

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm not convinced that poor programmers should guide your architecture. What do you mean by "abused"? If certain combinations of attributes must be set together then you can have a merged setter, e.g. `setName(String first, String last)`, but fundamentally there's no way to design around poor programmers. A bad programmer can send garbage XML with option 1 too.

Comment: I guess another way to do it would be something similar to option 2: Have a custom class for holding updated attributes that gets given to your data objects. This holder class could be XML-aware and that gives you the decoupling without masses of setters. It's a bit hacky, but it might be a worthwhile compromise.